# Change element style from controller Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

My code:

```
document.querySelector(".myTabs .line")[0].style.left = '30%' ;
```

By i have error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector(".myTabs .line")[0].style')

How i can change css style from controller?

Comment: Could you please add the code related to the view? And the component code where you want to modify the style?

Comment: It would be better to use Angular's NgClass (https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) than handle the css styles attributes directly.

Comment: HTML :

 `<a (click)="leftLine()"></a>
<div class="line"></div>`

Component code:

`leftLine() {
document.querySelector(".myTabs .line")[0].style.left = '30%' ;
}`

But 30% will be dynamic value

Comment: document.querySelector(".myTabs .line") will only get first matched element. [0] after it is wrong. It should be document.querySelector(".myTabs .line").style.left = '30%' ;

Comment: I try that, but have error `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.querySelector` will return the first element match with type is `Element`. You need to convert it to `HTMLElement`. Try this:

```
let elm = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(".myTabs .line");
elm.style.left = '30%'
```

Comment: if my element id in $event.currentTarget.id how can i send it to queryselector as input? is this standard? let row=document.querySelector("."+event.currentTarget.id);  after that i need to call sub element sth like this : row.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].hidden how to do it in ionic3

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi You can use `event.currentTarget` directly as a HTML element. `event.currentTarget.style.left = '30%'`